# Computer works correctly but CPU fan won't run

Tags: motherboard, fan

I got a used pc from my job since a week.

The motherboard is an Intel, model DDG965WH.

CPU is Core2 quad.

I installed Linux Mint on it.

Everything's ok since a couple of days, but I just realized that the CPU fan is not running. As far as I know, it has never runned since I have the pc.

Is it normal that the CPU fan does not always run? Maybe it will start up when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the computer is on, so should the CPU fan (unless its sleeping).
Its probably unplugged or broken.

Comment: It was just not plugged correctly...

Answer (score 2):

CPU fans always run.  Likely yours failed.  The new generation of CPU's have automatic throttling based on heat so your processor probably is just slowing down to keep the heat managable without the fan.  With the system off, try and spin the fan to see if it turns.  If not, replace it.  If it does, you can try plugging it into another jack of similar type.  You should definitely get this fixed since the thermal throttling is definitely killing your performance.